# Umbraco how to customize bubble message in EventHandler

Tags: c#, umbraco

My Umbraco version is 4.0.3.

```
public class MemberEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    public MemberEventHandler()
    {
        Member.BeforeSave += new Member.SaveEventHandler(Member_BeforeSave);
    }
    
    void Member_BeforeSave(umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.SaveEventArgs e)
    {         
        e.Cancel = true;
        var clientTool = new ClientTools((Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler);
        clientTool.ShowSpeechBubble(SpeechBubbleIcon.Success, "Error", "GroupName doesn't exist.");                            
    }
}
```

Now, I can cancel the save action by setting `e.Cancel` to true,
but the Umbraco's bubble still show "Member Saved" on the page.
I try the clientTools, but it can't work.

Could I customize the message in the bubble? Or show the Umbraco's error bubble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that in later v4 versions, it shows a message if the event was cancelled, but you can't customise it. In that particular version though (which is super old), I think you still get the message, even if you cancel it.

Comment: Can I do that with others way? Like injecting a javascript to page or catch the Umbraco postback and modify it.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, however, if you can upgrade to 7.3 or higher, this functionality is now supported (content and media only currently), see the issue here (example code is in the comments): http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5927

Comment: I know V7 is supported but I can't upgrade. I searched this issue for days but no answer. Maybe I need to modify the source code to achieve that.